# macro to send mails with selected range (only rows that abide by if condition)

Tags: vba, excel, email

I have created a macro which automatically sends part of an excel sheet via email to some recipients. The code is fully functional and is working great.

However, I want to implement a minor change to it: The macro is actually filtering a range (a column), it copies the rows that exist after the filtering and then pastes then in another sheet.
After that, it sends the copy-pasted range to some recipients.

What I want to change is, to tell the macro to send only the copy pasted rows that have values inside and not only 0.
So, if a row (every row has 8 columns with data) has only 0 in all of its columns then don't send this one.

I will provide the code below. It should be easy to add an If condition but I have tried and failed. Possibly someone knows how to add the If condition inside the code.

```
Sub MAIL()
    Dim ToArray As String
    Dim CCArray As String
    Dim Subject As String
    Dim Content As String
    Dim lastrow1 As Integer
    Dim lastrow2 As Integer
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For I = 1 To 20
    Sheets.Add.Name = "WS1"
    Sheets("Report").Activate
    ToArray = "aaa@gmail.com"
    'ToArray = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Report").Cells((I + 2), 28).Value
    CCArray = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Report").Cells((I + 2), 29).Value
    Subject = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Report").Cells((I + 2), 30).Value
    Content = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Report").Cells((I + 2), 31).Value
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Report").Range("I24:U24").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Report").Cells((I + 2), 27).Value
    lastrow1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Report").Cells(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Report").Rows.Count, "U").End(xlUp).Row
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Report").Range("K24:U" & lastrow1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WS1").Cells(1, 1)
    lastrow2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WS1").Cells(Sheets("WS1").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    If lastrow2 >= 2 Then
        Sheets("WS1").Columns("A:M").AutoFit
        Sheets("WS1").Activate
        Sheets("WS1").Range("A1:M" & lastrow2).Select
        ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
        With Sheets("Report").MailEnvelope
          .Introduction = Content
          .Item.To = ToArray
          .Item.CC = CCArray
          .Item.Subject = Subject
          .Item.Send
        End With
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    End If
    Sheets("WS1").Delete
    Next I
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you may try add `Criteria2:="<>0"` in your filtering code line:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Report").Range("I24:U24").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Report").Cells((I + 2), 27).Value
```

If it doesn't work on a single line, you probably should try to `AutoFilter` on a next statement. Please note in this case, it would be `Criteria1`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.. Unfortunatelly, it stills pastes the rows where everything is 0.. However, I dont know if its important to mention it, but in the first two columns of the range there are some type of vertical headers, so there are no values there.. the values start from the third row of the range... is it important?

Comment: Alright, it's somewhat hard to find a solution for you if we cannot test it by ourselves; what I can suggest is executing your script step by step to better understand how it is running (and what happens). It could give you some clues.

Comment: @PericlesFaliagas Did you manage to get the desired results? Or did you find where things starts to go wrong while executing step by step?

Comment: hey ! I actually tried a different method and worked better! I simply created an assisting sheet to move the range there and then edit it while being isolated. Thanks for the interest though!